# How to install mod_proxy_hcheck module/extension for apache2

Tags: apache2, load-balancing, mod-proxy

How to install mod_proxy check module/extension for apache2 ? I want to use all the latest mod_proxy ProxyPass parameters. Currently it is throwing compilation error saying

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 8 of /etc/apache2/conf-extra/httpd-proxy-balancer.conf:
BalancerMember unknown Worker parameter
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it by executing

```
a2enmod proxy_hcheck
```

Comment: Thanks, this did work for me on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Apache `Server version: Apache/2.4.51 (Ubuntu) Server built:   2021-10-07T19:17:29`